# ImageMagick's "import" command line program failing to take a screenshot from CRON script

Tags: linux, shell, cron, script

Hello I wrote a simple command line script
which is suppose to take my screenshot every 5 minutes.

(using ImageMagick's "import" program)

here is the script (shottr.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
```

```
PTH="/home/username/images"
NM=`date +%j`_`date +"%F %k:%M"`

/usr/bin/import -window root -resize 1024 "$PTH/$NM.png" &
echo "Screenshot" | festival --tts &
```

this is working fine if I execute by hand i.e:

```
# ./shottr.sh
```

or

```
#sh shottr.sh
```

the cron is set like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /home/username/scripts/shottr.sh
```

the script itself is being executed (I hear a voice saying: "Screenshot") but the actual screenshot is not taken.

P.S: Be assured that it is NOT permission issue (I placed a simple "touch" invocation and file was created)

may be if it's run from cron...it doesn't have a "window" so it can't take a screenshot from nowhere?? If that is the case, then how can I workaround it?

Comment: Yes, the invocation from cron is most likely the issue here.

Comment: Any idea what is the workaround to this? I need to take screenshots every 5 minutes

Comment: what happens if just for a test you set NM=test, just to ensure its not a problem with your date command.

Comment: But it works if I invoke by hand. However I tested as you said and nothing...

Comment: Your date string can be simplified to: `NM=$(date "+%j_%F %k:%M")` (no need to run `date` twice). Putting the Julian day number first ruins the sortability of the filenames and you might want to consider not including a space.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, for the tip. And you are right about the naming. Fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you're running the script from `cron` it doesn't have access to your `DISPLAY` environment variable, which is how it knows what X11 display with which to interact.  You may be able to get it to work by adding the following to your script:

```
# Set display to :0 if it's not already set.
: ${DISPLAY:=:0}
export DISPLAY
```

This assumes that your `DISPLAY` is always `:0`, which is true if you're logging in on the console but not true if you're running X remotely.

Comment: Oh man you ROCk! This worked! You cool.

P.S: Hey guys please vote up!

Comment: @bakytn, if this answer solved your problem you should accept it (click the checkbox to the left).  Thanks!